# Add option to delete messages in the mobile app

Tags: support, android-app, self-delete

Add option to delete messages in the mobile app. I often use a mobile Stack Exchange app *on Android*, but when there is a need to delete your question or answer, I can't do it. You have to go to the browser, log in account... Is it possible to add this feature in next version?

Comment: TL;DR: won't happen, since both apps are frozen by now without any developer assigned to work on them.

Comment: Worth to mention, iOS app does allow deleting your own posts (I think), while the android app doesn't have even this. :(

Comment: @ShadowWizard, but I just saw the app update in Google Play...

Comment: What version? Anyway, even if "new" version, it's just to update the ToS following GDPR and stuff, there's not a single bug fix or new feature done for years.